# Wacom Cintiq 16 and Ubuntu 20.04 - how to set the default screen permanently?

Tags: xorg, tablet, wacom, xorg.conf

I want to use a Cintiq 16 on Ubuntu 20.04. It works somehow but with an annoying "feature":

The tablet can be switched on and off, and every time I do that, it loses its pen area settings. I have two monitors and it should just be mapped to the first one. The tablet's screen works fine showing just my first screen without any problems but the pen acts as if both screens were one.

I can manually map this via

```
xsetwacom -v set "Wacom Cintiq 16 Pen stylus" MapToOutput HEAD-1
```

but it resets itself each time I turn the tablet off and on again. I managed to define an alias to have a shortcut command. But the most convenient solution would be if I can somehow define the default behaviour. Such that it is always mapped to the first screen.

I read that this can be done in a `wacom.conf` file. I think found mine in `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/70-wacom.conf`. But I was not able to figure out what to change in here to get it to work and I am a bit afraid to do something wrong.

I think this is done by an "area" option, but even via command line, I am unable to reproduce my MapToOutput result with the area option...

`xsetwacom -v get "Wacom Cintiq 16 Pen stylus" area` gives
`400 400 69232 39118` as default area. I tried `xsetwacom -v set "Wacom Cintiq 16 Pen stylus" area 400 400 34416 39118` assuming that I should half the x width: (69232 - 400)/2 = 34416 but that did not work.

Can anyone please tell me what exactly I have to add/modify in my `.conf` file?

Answer (score 0):

To make your changes permanent, simply open (or create) the file .xsessionrc in your home directory and add the following lines (in your case):

```
xsetwacom set "Wacom Cintiq 16 Pen stylus" MapToOutput HEAD-1
xsetwacom set "Wacom Cintiq 16 Pen eraser" MapToOutput HEAD-1
```

It should work...

Comment: Unfortunately, this did not work...
When I have the tablet turned on on startup, it works but when I turn it off and on again, settings still reset...